# How to find a child html element by id with jsoup?

Tags: html, search, jsoup, element

I am parsing the html code of one site with Jsoup. I need to find some html elements that has an specific id but their parent´s tree is complicating me the task. So I would like to know if is it possible to search an specific html element without having to search first all of their parents.

For instance I am doing the next:

```
Elements el=elements.select(".scroller.context-inplay").select(".zone.grid-1-1").select(".grid-1").select(".module-placeholder");
```

I would likte to know if there is a simple way to get the same element I get with this code searching by its id

Comment: Can you share your HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The id of an html element should be unique within the page. Some html that you find in the wild breaks this requirement unfortunately tough. However, if your html source follows the standard you can simply use the `#` css operator to select the element in question:

```
 Element el = doc.select("#someID").first();
```

Alternatively you can directly use the [getElmentById](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#getElementById-java.lang.String-) Jsoup method:

```
Element el = doc.getElmentById("someID");
```

Also, if you decide to go by class names as you suggest in your question, it is easy to combine all selects into one selector:

```
Elements els = elements.select(".scroller.context-inplay .zone.grid-1-1 .grid-1 .module-placeholder");
```

The spaces in the CSS selector mean that any subselector right of the space must be a child of the stuff on the left side.

Comment: Is it possible that the page creates ids using a Firefox and doesn´t create the ids when I use Jsoup?

Comment: It is possible, yes. A JavaScript can set und unset the id of any element after the page is loaded in the browser. JSoup does not run JavaScript, so you would not see the change when using JSoup. A more common scenario of this is however not the setting/changing of element ids but the loading of page parts via AJAX. You can check for this in the browser when you turn off JavaScript.